# Selecting by ID attribute using JQuery in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I've just started using JQuery in VS 2008, and so far I like it! But, I'm confused about how I should be using JQuery in order to select asp.net controls on a webpage.

For example, I have the following code (just a mock-up):

```
<asp:textbox id="txtSomeData1" runat="server" text="Some Data!!"></textbox>
```

Now, if I want to use JQuery to select the textbox and change it's text to "Some More Data!!", then I would have to do something like:

```
$('input#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSomeData1').val('Some More Data!!');
```

Which, quite frankly, is annoying because I don't want to mess with having to figure out what the id of the control is after it's rendered to the webpage (ctl00_ContextPlaceHolder... blah blah blah).

Is there a way that I can select the textbox without having to use the id of it? Also, I know that you can select by class name, but that doesn't help much if the control that you're selecting doesn't have a class.

Am I just missing something here?

**JUST TO REITERATE: I do not want to use a class to select the input tag!! I would like to use the id "txtSomeData1" and not the long id that is rendered to the webpage.**

Comment: If you have to change the ID of the element in the generated page, you'd have to change the output on the asp side. So this is more of an ASP question than a jquery question.

Comment: Made an edit to the title accordingly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you want to do is either:

```
$("input[id$='_txtSomeData1']").val().....
```

or you could add a class or custom attribute to the textbox that you can select on

Comment: I can't get this to work, but I think it's what I'm looking for! I haven't tried the custom attribute yet though. Is the $= a wildcard match?

Comment: This is exactly what I tried: $("input[id$='_txtSomeData1'").val('Some More Data!!');

Comment: you closed the double quote too early. $= looks for a string ending with the specified value... try $("input[id$='_txtSomeData1']").val('Some More Data!!');

Comment: Oh, duh! I missed the ending bracket as well. Must need more caffeine or something.

Comment: We use this as well for long winded gen'd ids, but try to use real selectors when you can simply for 'ye olde premature optimization' as this is a slower selector.

Comment: Someone needs to edit the solution to place the ending double quotes in the right place.

Comment: @Marc - what do you mean by "real selectors"??

Comment: Ooop, sorry about that... is fixed now :)

Comment: @Jagd - That was my horribly worded way of saying exact name selectors (non-wildcard)

Comment: Just be careful when referencing elements from data-bound controls (e.g. if you put _txtSomeData1 inside of item template of a data-bound control, such as Repeater, DataGrid, etc), since in this case the selector will return multiple elements.

Answer (score 7):

if the javascript is on the same .aspx file, you can do:

```
$('<%= txtSomeData1.ClientID %>').val('Some More Data!!');
```

Comment: The javascript is in it's own file (ie - non-obtrusive). But as I said to Vdex, it is a very appealing and easy-to-use solution; however, not the one I'm looking for.

Comment: Actually, this would be $('#<%= txtSomeData1.ClientID %>').val('Some More Data!!');  (note the # sign -- this is something I sometimes forget myself)

Comment: one technique that I've used is to map screen components to javascript objects; on the .aspx file you can do just the mapping (element id to property), then you can use those objects on the .js files

Answer (score 1):

This is a big complaint the community has with ASP.Net web forms. In ASP.Net 4.0 you get control of your IDs back so it's like you're wrote it in raw HTML. Alternatively, without .Net 4.0, you could use ASP.Net MVC which, for the most part, doesn't use server controls, so you wouldn't have the issue.

But like happytime harry says, adding a class may be want you want if you're working with web forms and jquery.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know that 4.0 won't have the annoying id's to screw around with. That is good news.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to externalise the JavaScript to its own .js file you are stuck with either hard coding in the id (most efficient), some regular expression selector or using the inefficient by class name selector.

However if it is in the same file as the .NET control you could always use `$('<%=txtSomeData1.ClientID %>')`

Comment: I do have the javascript in a js file and I'll likely keep it that way, but I must admit that your solution has some appeal to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of selectors to use... maybe adding a class is what you want to do.

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Wildcard Selectors](http://colourgray.wordpress.com/2008/08/05/jquery-wildcard-selectors/) are what you may be missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'marker' classes to any control whose sole purpose is for use in a jQuery selector.
That, along with navigating the tree heirarchy (something like `"$(element).children('.myClass').show()"` might be a good way to do this without IDs.

Btw, http://visualjquery.com/ is a great way to view the jQuery APIs etc.

Comment: VisualJquery is great.  If only they'd update it to the current version that has been out for like 6 months now...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the element[id$=Identifier] notation, which looks for the id ending with the text you specify (it's the ID you specify in ASPX markup). Here is an example illustrating how you can use it (see slide #30): [Building intranet applications with ASP.NET AJAX and jQuery](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/5169680/Building-intranet-applications-with-ASPNET-AJAX-and-jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following syntax :
$("[id*=txtSomeData1]") to reference any asp control

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET Web Forms, you can use `ClientIDMode="Static"` to [prevent the id from changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641280/reference-asp-net-control-by-id-in-javascript#19766188):

```
<div id="MySection" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></div>
```

which means you can then reference the element in a separate plain JavaScript file if required, without having to embed the JavaScript in the `.aspx` file:

```
var mySection = document.getElementById("MySection");
```

and even add classes:

```
mySection.classList.add("hidden");
```

And the CSS used above for reference:

```
.hidden {
    display: none !important;
}
```