# Registering jQuery-script on master page code-behind doesn't affect scripts on MasterPage

Tags: jquery, scriptmanager, master-pages

in my .net-Project, I use a master page on which I dynamically register the 
jQuery-library.

```
public partial class Application : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this, this.GetType(), "jquery", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Materials/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"));
    }     
}
```

I found out that this works for all pages that are bound to the master page, but that a script on the master page itself throws an error. I still have to use a hardcoded link to get it working. I would like to understand better why this is so, what´s the problem and how one could get around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems necessary to reference the script in the markup of the master page.

[Link to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292787/how-to-use-jquery-with-master-pages)