# Trying to Use jQuery with Masterpages in asp.net 3.5--click function on checkbox control to trigger slideToggle on hidden div

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-3.5

I thought my question was answered over here at

[How to use JQuery with Master Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292787/how-to-use-jquery-with-master-pages)

but after trying the things suggested there, my code is still not working. I'm trying to get a checkbox control to toggle a hidden div below. Here's the code in my external .js file;

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
             alert("hello world");
         });//works

        $('[id$=parking]').click(function() {
        $('#parktype').slideToggle('slow');//doesn't work
        });
```

and here is the code in my .aspx file

```
<td class="vanilla">
            <div id="park"></div><asp:CheckBox ID="parking" runat="server" /></div>
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
        </div>


        <div id="parktype" style="display:none;width:540px;padding:20px;margin:auto;">
        <table width="75%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
         <tr>
```

Last but not least I have linked my masterpage to the jQuery library;

```
 <script src="../jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

As far as I can tell, the slideToggle function is not being triggered, and I suspect this is because of the difficulty in grabbing the name of a control in asp.net.

I've tried changing this:

```
 $('[id$=parking]').click(function() {
```

to many variations, including

```
 $('[id$=_parking]').click(function() {

 $('[id$="_parking"]').click(function() {

 $('[id$=ctl00_body_parking]').click(function() {
```

with the last variation being the ID given in the processed file;

```
 <td class="vanilla">
            <div id="park"></div><input id="ctl00_body_parking" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$body$parking" /></div>
          </td>
```

Not quite sure what I'm missing but thankful for any helpful hints, or whacks over the head indicating I'm just missing something really obvious...

Again, the goal is to have the div #parktype slideToggle when the asp.net control parking is clicked.
Merci!

Comment: will your code fire an alert with the selector you have added? Also - you seem to have too many cloding div tags in you markup - not sure if this will interfere, but better to get rid of them. Finally you want to put the text your trying to match in quotes = $('[id$="parking"]').click(function() {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your .js is external the document ready will not fire.
I'm a little rusty on my asp.net controls but i think you can set your OnClientClick Event to

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="parking" runat="server" OnClientClick="$('#parktype').slideToggle('slow');" />
```

or 
you can set the OnClientClick to a function which passes in the checkbox itself

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="parking" runat="server" OnClientClick="toggleParkType(this);" />
```

Here's a sample of the function

```
function toggleParkType(chkbox){
    $(chkbox).slideToggle();
    //   test if checked
    if($(chkbx).is(":checked")){
     // perform action for checked
    }
}
```

Comment: the document.ready will fire (and does as confirmed in the question).

Comment: the binding of the click function is outside the document.ready function.

Comment: Thank you! This worked once I changed OnClientClick to a simple OnClick

Comment: Cool, glad it worked for you. It's been awhile since i worked with asp.net server controls, and I remember having to use OnClientClick() if i had a conflicting server side method for OnClick().

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("hello world");

  $('[id$="parking"]').click(function() {
    $('#parktype').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

Additionally you should review the comment I left on your question about the div tags

Answer (score 0):

Try to use change function.

```
     $(document).ready(function() {         
       $('[id$=parking]').change(function() {
              $('#parktype').slideToggle('slow');
        });
    });
```