# Jquery date time picker not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I used the jQuery date time picker with a button image. It's not showing and not working....

This is ascx.cs file:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ExclusionSwipeCardRequest.ascx.cs" Inherits="ExclusionSwipeCardRequest" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<link href="../App_Themes/LMSTheme/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#<%=txtFromDate.ClientID%>" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "Images/clock_add.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Textbox:

```
<td>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" MaxLength="10" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter From Date"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFVIssueDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFromDate" ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup="Enter">
     </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
```

Comment: Is there an error message of some kind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well why do you use echo for the ID?

And you are trying to use the **jQuery UI** (NOT jquery) DatePicker, so you should include their library :)
(http://jqueryui.com/download)
See http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ for more info.

Comment: DatePicker is nice but you just have to use their package. Go to http://jqueryui.com/download and download the framework :)

Answer (score 0):

Is DateTimePicker part of Jquery ui, then you have to include jquery ui!

Edit: Oh sorry same answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Marco Johannesen said, make sure the ID or class of the TextBox is actually being selected by the jQuery selector. Usually, if you're using a MasterPage, this ID is modified concatenating the ContentPlaceHolder ID at the beginning of the ID. More info: [How to use JQuery with Master Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292787/how-to-use-jquery-with-master-pages)