# retrieve id of textbox from content place holder in jquery function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui, contentplaceholder

I am using JQUERY UI for my web pages. I am trying to use datepicker control. The problem is jquery function is not taking the textbox ID. It is working when I concatenate the content placeholder id with textbox id.

```
<asp:Content ID="PassportContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPH001" runat="server">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Date Of Birth</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server" CssClass="txt-control"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

**actual jquery code**

```
<script src="../jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

**working jquery code**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var temp = document.getElementById('<%= datepicker.ClientID %>').value;
        alert(temp);
        $("#CPH001_datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

When I searched in forums most of the solutions suggested to use `document.getElementById`, I tried getting the ID using >>

`document.getElementById('<%= datepicker.ClientID %>').value`; but the alert box is showing NULL.

1. How to solve this problem?
2. When I keep my js code in seperate file, how to solve this problem ?

As suggested, I used `$("[id$=datepicker]").datepicker();`. And it works I am getting the datepicker. But I cannot change the date format and restrict the date range. Please suggest.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("[id$=datepicker]").datepicker();        

        $("[id$=datepicker]").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'ISO 8601 - yy-mm-dd' }); // not working
    });
    // not working
    $("#format").change(function () { $("[id$=datepicker]").datepicker('ISO 8601 - yy-mm-dd', "dateFormat", $(this).val()); });
</script>
```

Comment: You can just set ClientIDMode="Static" in asp:TextBox. This would create the rendered element with the actual id defined, and then you can use $("#datepicker").datepicker();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Content page renders `Textbox` id Changes. Use `Textbox` id like this

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("[id$=datepicker]").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

See [How to use JQuery with Master Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292787/how-to-use-jquery-with-master-pages)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works. One question >> Will it work too when I keep the js code in separate file ? Also, I tried restricting the date range, but the code is not working.                                                                            
`$("[id$=datepicker]").datepicker();
            $("[id$=datepicker]").datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
            $("#format").change(function () {
                $("[id$=datepicker]").datepicker('ISO 8601 - yy-mm-dd', "dateFormat", $(this).val());
            });`

Comment: Yes it will work if you keep js in separate file. But i am confused about the date range. Which range of year/date you want to show?? Example like if you want to use 1990 to present use some thing like      `  $(function () {
            $("[id$=datepicker]").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                yearRange: "1990:+0"
                                           });
                                           });`

Answer (score 0):

Try it with an input field, your code is correct:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" runat="server" CssClass="txt-control" />
```

I'm not sure if jquery can handel an "asp:TextBox" tag or will it be replaced?

Comment: what is the difference b/n `asp:TextBox` and `input`. How does `input` effect my code.

Comment: as i understand you this pice of code is not working `$("#datepicker").datepicker();`...maybe it expect an input tag but im not sure like i said, you can try.